# GoLang: TLS client error `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

Tags: go, ssl, tls1.3

I have followed multiple tutorials [[1](https://github.com/denji/golang-tls) , [2](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls@go1.20.4#pkg-overview), [3](https://forfuncsake.github.io/post/2017/08/trust-extra-ca-cert-in-go-app/)] to write a client-server in Go that accepts TLS authentication.

I have my server certificates and keys named:

- `server_cert.pem`,
- `server_key.pem`, and
- `server_cacerts.pem`

The server code looks as follows:

```golang
    path, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    CACert := path + "/server_cacerts.pem"
    log.Println(CACert)

    certs, err := ioutil.ReadFile(CACert)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Invalid CACert: %s", err)
    }

    rootCAs := x509.NewCertPool()
    ok := rootCAs.AppendCertsFromPEM(certs)
    if !ok {
        log.Println("Taking default certificates")
    }

    certPem := path + "/server_cert.pem"
    keyPem := path + "/server_key.pem"
    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(certPem, keyPem)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Println(certPem)
    log.Println(keyPem)

    config := &tls.Config{Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
                          // ServerName: "elxa3x9nxd3",
                          ClientAuth: tls.RequireAndVerifyClientCert,
                          ClientCAs: rootCAs}

    ln, err := tls.Listen("tcp", ":8888", config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("listen failed: %s", err.Error())
        return
    }
    defer ln.Close()

    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Accept Failed: %s", err.Error())
            continue
        }
        // log.Printf("connection open: %s", conn.RemoteAddr())
        // printConnState(conn.(*tls.Conn))
        go handleConnection(conn)
    }
```

and the client certificates and keys named:

- `client_cert.pem`,
- `client_key.pem`, and
- `client_cacerts.pem`

Client code follows:

```golang
func main() {
    log.SetFlags(log.Lshortfile)
    args := os.Args

    var numberHandshakes int
    var err error

    if len(args) > 1 {
        numberHandshakes, err = strconv.Atoi(args[1])
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Error in number of arguments")
            panic(err)
        }
    } else {
        numberHandshakes = 1000
    }
    fmt.Println("Number of handshakes requested: " + strconv.Itoa(numberHandshakes))


    path, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    CACert := path + "/client_cacerts.pem"
    certs, err := ioutil.ReadFile(CACert)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // rootCAs := x509.NewCertPool()
    rootCAs, err := x509.SystemCertPool()
    ok := rootCAs.AppendCertsFromPEM(certs)
    if !ok {
        log.Println("Taking default certificates")
    }


    certPem := path + "/client_cert.pem"
    keyPem := path + "/client_key.pem"
    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(certPem, keyPem)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error loading KeyPair: %s", err)
    }

    conf := &tls.Config{ Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
                         // InsecureSkipVerify: true,
                         ServerName: "elxa3x9nxd3",
                         RootCAs: rootCAs,
                        }

    ch := make(chan int)
    for i := 1; i <= numberHandshakes; i++ {
        go func(){
            conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", ":8888", conf)      // ERROR HERE
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("Error in client", err.Error())
                return
            }

            conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Time{})
            conn.Write([]byte(strconv.Itoa(i)))
        }()
    }
}
```

I run the server and then call the client to perform some number of queries to the server.
The error seems to be in the line marked as `ERROR HERE`, and the error that I see says:

```
tls-client.go:98: Error in client tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I know that I have self-signed a certificate, but I thought that given the client and server options that I have in my code, I do not need to throw out of the window any security (I do not want to enable `InsecureSkipVerify`).

Any tips?

Comment: Please show us how you generated the server certificates (it's difficult to work out your file naming etc from the tutorials; easier if you give us something [we can run](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). It's possible that you have confused the CA's; the client needs the CA used to sign the server certificate (and I'm guessing that's probably `server_cacerts.pem` not `client_cacerts.pem`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `server_cacerts.pem` contains the root CA and possible intermediate CAs which are used to create `server_cert.pem` and the same for `client_*.pem`.

Since the client needs to verify the server certificate and this is done using `server_cacerts.pem` the client needs this as `RootCA`, not `client_cacerts.pem` as done in your code. Similar with mutual authentication the server needs to verify the client certificate and thus needs `client_cacerts.pem` as `ClientCA`, not `server_cacerts.pem` as done in your code.